# Receiving empty email from a delayed job Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, sendgrid

I'm sending an email with a delayed job from a rails app, we get the email as well but received empty only with subscription email link at the bottom, but any content as well.

When I send it normally without a delayed job we get it with content and it display ok, I already check Email Activity on Sendgrid and it display my emails. We are not sure what could be causing this bug.

Already talked with Engine Yard guys and told us that can be Subscription Tracking app, but we already disabled it and it's not...

I will appreciate any clue about this...

Answer (score 1):

Probably this might be because the what ever the parameter which you are sending as the mail content is not correctly passing to delayed_job

```
class GenerateFileJob < Struct.new(:claim_id)
  def perform
    claim = Claim.find(claim_id)
    #do some stuff 
  end
end
```

Above is a sample code when I used in my app with delayed job, if you could paste any code we might be able to help you more

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I'm not sure that is something wrong with the code because I already sent another email with delayed job and it's OK.

Comment: great, I also notice that some times delayed job behave strange when you only restart the web server, anyway if you find the cause of the issue, pls do post it in here :D